# How do I get a ssh session using android studio Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an android app that requires an ssh session to be started , and a command to be ran , I've heard about JSH and it seems like just what i need but , am unsure on how to use it in tandem with android studio - can anyone help?

To give more context - my app is a Fingerprint unlock client intended to be used alongside Linux desktops

My relevant code is as such:

```
       Button authenticate = findViewById(R.id.authenticate);
    final MainActivity activity = this;
    authenticate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            biometricPrompt.authenticate(new CancellationSignal(), executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unlocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //I assume this is where the ssh stuff would go
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the ssh session supposed to do?  Are you just having it run a remote command, do you expect a full interactive terminal, etc?

Comment: I just want to run a remote command that's all.